# Is there a name for the literary device of having multiple speakers alternating in the same paragraph?

Tags: writing-style, writing, literary-device

In *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader,* C. S. Lewis has:

> . . . Lucy could only say, "It would break your heart." "Why," said I, "was it so sad?" "Sad!! No," said Lucy

and in the *Star Trek* novel, *The Wounded Sky,* Diane Duane has (in one of many nods to Narnia -- the whole book is, in many ways, one big homage to Narnia) an almost-verbatim quote, using the same device of two speakers alternating in a single paragraph.

Is there a formal name for this device?

Note that I'm not accusing Diane Duane of plagiarism here: the Narnian nods are too obvious for her not to have intended readers familiar with Narnia to recognize them.

Comment: We're likely to get only ballpark answers or DIY non-words here, which is not what ELU requires. I'll give time for the highly improbable correct answer (other than the trivial 'no') before close-voting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could you clarify that a little? Is it standard practice on ELU to close questions that don't have an answer? i.e. where the question itself is clear, and is asking for a word, say, and one doesn't exist. What's the exact close reason that's used in this case?

Comment: @cigien This has been discussed on ELU.meta; the title is irretrievable, along the lines of 'Should a question such as '"Is there a word for a pinkish green cross between a car and a printing-press that has been broken when being serviced?" be allowed?' Possibly 'Too narrowly scoped'. As I said, this question might just have a valid answer ('No' trivialises the site, and is impossible to prove, and a lone 'Yes' would be ludicrous: OP wants a real answer), but I very much doubt it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm, I'll try to look up these discussions on ELU Meta, thanks. I just found your comment a little surprising since on the SE sites I tend to frequent (though I'm starting to get more active on ELU), whether a question should be closed is judged on whether it's clear what the question is asking, not whether it actually has an answer or not. Answers that say "no" are valid, but rare, since it's usually hard to prove a negative. Of course, I understand that different sites have different criteria.

Comment: I wonder if writing.stackexchange.com would help; you might have to phrase the question slightly differently to meet their rules, asking a more general question about why this is done and what effect it creates and whether it is considered valid and what rules there are for doing this, rather than purely "what's this called?"

Comment: As it happens, before I even got the idea to ask here, I asked on TrekBBS, in the thread where the subject first came up, and a novelist who is highly respected in Star Trek circles (and who has written a fair amount of original science fiction as well) opined that there wasn't a name for the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this applies, but there's a very related term in drama and poetry called [stichomythia](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stichomythia)

> A form of verbal sparring used especially in ancient Greek drama or poetry, in which single lines of verse or parts of lines are spoken by alternate speakers.

and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stichomythia)

> Dialogue especially of altercation or dispute delivered by two actors in alternating lines (as in classical Greek drama).

It might not be too much of a stretch to use this term to describe a literary device as well.

Comment: Won't the single lines be paragraph-formatted (or equivalent) in plays / poems? OP's examples are prose from books.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, all the examples I found were formatted like that. As I mentioned, it's a bit of a stretch to apply this term to prose, but I feel it's reasonably close enough to qualify as an answer.

Comment: I'm very close to disagreeing. It's a very rare word, and pushing it to such a broadened usage seems very non-standard. Of course, if you can find a reasonable authority that has done so ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, that's fair. I'll see if I can find a reference where this connection has been made before, and if I can't something reasonable, I'll probably go ahead and delete the answer.